# What is the meaning of Technology, Package and Variant with regards to an electronic component?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, components

I am currently designing a PCB in EAGLE and while creating a footprint/package of a logic IC (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sdls029c/sdls029c.pdf) I came across the terms technology, package, and variant.

P.S.: I know what package means and that the IC might be available in EAGLE as a device. I have just mentioned it as an example.

Answer (score 1):

An IC may be available in multiple variants and packages. For example, an OPAMP might be available in a SOIC or TSSOP and QFN version. Ofcourse, it is quite important that you get the right type since one will not fit on the other's footprint.

In addition, there might be multiple variants of the chip. Take as example this OPAMP from Analog devices: [Datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8676.pdf)

This chip is available in multiple grades. There is a high and low input offset version (well, low and lower really). These different versions need to be specified so you get the right part for your design. 
There are also temperature grades: One version of the chip might be "rated" to work from 0 degrees Celsius to 75 degrees Celsius. But for the automotive market they might release a version (which is of course more expensive) that is rated from -50 to 125 degrees Celsius.  Similar situations apply for medical, military, etc.

Technology can mean many things, but I would assume it refers to the type of package: through-hole, surface-mount, flipchip, bare die.

Comment: 100% correct. Good answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that your last sentence reflects how Eagle intends for the Technology field to be used. For a given library device, Eagle allows you to specify different Packages, each with a different Variant name (you can also have the similar Packages with  different pinouts). Each Variant then contains different Technologies (each having their own Attributes). Eagle's documentation specifies that a 74*00 hex inverter might include several different Technologies (e.g. 7400, 74LS00, 74HCT00), despite the fact that each of those "technologies" is available in different packages/footprints.